# Raspberry Pi Pico always opening the folder like boot

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

Everytime when I connect the Pico in my computer, without push the boot bottom, appear the boot folder.
So I can't programming anything on the pico.
Suggestions?

Comment: Possibility #1: You didn't copy the firmware correctly last time.

Answer (score 0):

Your first Pico may be malfunctioning. To test that, try another pico and see whether it behaves the same way.
If not try the Pico on another computer, if it has the same misbehaviour there, the chances are high that it is malfunctioning.